# Creating label in Scatter Matplotlib from dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have DataFrame (dfcell) as showed in a sample bellow:

[image]

This DataFrame has 104 rows and I need to show in Scatter Plot.

The columns `location_cell_lng` and `location_cell_lat` are Cartesian axis and `class_m` is the target.

I did that

```
plt.scatter(dfcell['location_cell_lng'], dfcell['location_cell_lat'], c=dfcell['class_m'])
```

I don't get to put legend to the column class_m that has a range of 0 to 5.

I tried the code in the link bellow, but without success
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-with-legend-py

How can I to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `label="mylabel"` as an argument to `plt.scatter`
then call the `plt.legend()` method

```
# dummy data for classes
class_m = [ 0 for x in range(5)] + [ 1 for x in range(5)]

# create dataframe
dfcell = pd.DataFrame({"location_cell_lng":range(10),"location_cell_lat":range(10),"class_m":class_m})

# create a dictionary to color the different classes
color_dict = {0:"red",1:"blue"}

# create column with colors
dfcell["colors"] = dfcell["class_m"].apply(color_dict.get)

# plot
plt.scatter(dfcell['location_cell_lng'], dfcell['location_cell_lat'], c=dfcell['colors'],label="mylabel")
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for answer!
But I need of different color according the value target (class_m)

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how you can color according to the different classes.